# Googlemaps v3 directions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a new Google maps for my website which always used v2. Everything is going fine till last detail...after asking directions I know there "should" be a line drawn on the map which visualizes the directions. That blue line is not showing on my map and tried many things but no luck...any suggestions are highly appreciated!
For anyone who would like to see the script in action: http://www.pruikenboer.nl/googlev3.html
Thanks in advance!
Chris

Answer (score 1):

You create the map twice, at first the map where you want to draw the route, then onload a new map, which overwrites the first one.

Solution: create only 1 map-object

Comment: damn...can't get both work together. Seperately they work indeed (except the directionmap doesn't show onload but after directions are requested...). Could you please help me out integrating the 2 together? I've tried different things but end up with no directions...